# Passing Value from C++ to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, json, parameter-passing, v8

i have a c++ file which reads values from a sensor and I want to display those values on a website dynamically. So Im looking for a way to pass these values(integers) from my cpp file to an javascript which displays them on the site.

My first, simple try was to write the values into a js file as variables every second from my cpp script. The Js then uses this file as a source and displays its variables on the site:

cpp:

```
fprintf(file, "var mx=%d, my=%d, mz=%d, ax=%d, ay=%d, az=%d, gx=%d, gy=%d, gz=%d;\n",
    imu.raw_m[0], imu.raw_m[1], imu.raw_m[2],       // M = Magnetometer
    imu.raw_a[0], imu.raw_a[1], imu.raw_a[2],       // A = Accelerometer
    imu.raw_g[0], imu.raw_g[1], imu.raw_g[2]        // G = Gyroscope
);
```

html/js:

```
<script src="./imu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The Problem now is of course, that I need to refresh the page all the time, because the imu.js file is cached by the website.

I'd rather have a way to directly pass to integers from the cpp file to the js script. I read something about json or Googles V8 script. But I'd like to hear your suggestions first.

By the way, Im running this on a raspi, if this is important.

Thanks for your help

EDIT:

I'm goning to try it with a mysql database, in which my cpp file writes the data from the sensor with Connector/c++ from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/ and my website reads them.

Comment: An easy way to do this would be for your C++ program to act as an http server, and then the script can just request data from it using XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: Nice idea, but making an HTTP server in C++ is not especially easy.

Comment: @SkyHigh Yeah, you're gonna want to actually send the data, not just rewrite a file that needs to be loaded later. You might want to look into Node.js + C++ or Boost.Asio

Comment: Maybe you can use some C++ REST framework to expose an API to which your website can periodically send queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compile your C++ code into a Node.js plugin, you can then register a JavaScript function with your plugin which the C++ calls when it updates the value.  That way you can pass values directly from C++ into Javascript in a managed and controlled way.

Node.js has the added benefit of being able to host your webpage and do all the Websocket and HTTP stuff that can be a pain in C++.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to refresh if your script is smart about how to access the data file! In case you do have a webserver at hand: Take care that your data file is accessible by your webserver and then let your script request the file via ajax ([link to w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_examples.asp))

Comment: This link is dead. You should add it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar on a BeagleBone Black. With websocketd you can turn pretty much any program into a websocket endpoint and then send data via stdin and stdout commands. This would be a particularly good solution for you since websockets are designed to handle information that's constantly changing.